# plantuml activity diagram how do I add color to part of a process name

Tags: plantuml

I want to highlight part of a process name in an activity diagram to make it stand out.

```
@startuml
start
  :process 1;
:process 2\nSend email;
end
@enduml
```

I want to make the text of the second line of process 2 red, but just that portion of text.
According to some examples I saw on the plantuml forum, I should be able to use something like:

```
:process 2\n<#red>Send email;
```

But when i generated an svg from the code I see `<#red> in the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
@startuml
start
  :process 1;
:process 2\n<color:red>Send email</color>;
end
@enduml
```

[image]